# How to use AddressComponents from the new Places API?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I've been using the new Places API for Android. I want to know how to get City, Country etc details from AddressComponents.

This is how I'm using it:

```
private void initializePlacesAPI()
    {
        if(!Places.isInitialized())
        {
            Places.initialize(context.getApplicationContext(), Constants.GOOGLE_API_KEY);
        }
    }

private void launchPlacesAPI(int requestCode)
    {
        // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return after the user has made a selection.
        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS);

        // Start the autocomplete intent.
        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                .setCountry(Constants.COUNTRY_CODE_CANADA)
                .setHint(context.getString(R.string.start_typing_an_address))
                .build(context);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
```

When a `Place` object is received in `onActivityResult`, how do I use the `AddressComponents` object received there? It has no getters/setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSON` response should look something like this

```
    "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "5",
        "short_name" : "5",
        "types" : [ "floor" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "48",
        "short_name" : "48",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
        "short_name" : "Pirrama Rd",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
     }
```

SO you can acess information like this

```
    String floor = place.addressComponent[0].long_name
```

You can find more informations here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: So I've to use addressComponents.get(0).getName() and then match that name with what I want? Isn't this very.. expensive? Also, what 'type' do they use for city?